# How to validate localization mappings at build time

Tags: visual-studio, localization, blazor, visual-studio-extensions

I have blazor pages with localization like this:

```
<NoRecordsContent>@Localizer["No Content"]</NoRecordsContent>
```

What I want to know is if there is a Visual Studio extension, build pipeline component, etc. that would detect and report that any particular key is missing from the localization resource file.

In the example above, if "No Content" key didn't have a corresponding translation for a given language I want to know that at build time.